# Share Path with File?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document, share

In SharePoint Online, I have a Document Library which is restricted to only members of a specific user group (call this Library `/`).

When a file located at `/Folder A/Folder B/File.txt` is shared (Read Only) to someone that normally wouldn't have access to `Folder B`, they are unable to access the file without a view that shows all items outside of their Folders (even if they follow the share link).

Is there a way to share the full file path along with the file (but not all contents of `Folder A` or `Folder B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this would be to create a view with audience targeting and place the users for folder B in the group to access the view.  Folders are just another list item in regards to permissions.  Create a new security group with what permissions you want for the folder B users and apply audience targeting to a new view.